# How to use data variable in iframe linked url in html page without url parameter or GET and POST

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In my HTML page, I used an iframe. In this iframe, I am showing a bar chart. I want to transfer data from my HTML page to iframe without GET or POST data. How can use data in iframe link? Is it possible to use this variable in iframe link is visible there or not in other pages?

if yes it is possible then how we can achieve it 
if no then what we way follow to achieve this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Page1.html

```
<iframe id="iframe1" data-value="yourdata" src="page2.html"></iframe>
```

Page2.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(parent.document.getElementById("iframe1").getAttribute("data-value"));
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: parent.getElementById is not a function

Comment: Sorry but I corrected the problem.  Should be parent.document.getElementById not parent.getElementById

Answer (score 0):

**1) Solution:** location.hash

*index.html*

```
<iframe src="iframe.html#extraHashDataNotSendToServer"></iframe>
```

*iframe.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(location.hash); // "#extraHashDataNotSendToServer"
</script>
```

**2) Solution:** [window.postMessage(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

*index.html*

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" name="target">

<script>
    var win = window.frames.target;
    // Send message to iframe.html
    win.postMessage('Message to iframe', '*');

    // Get message from iframe.html
    window.addEventListener('message', e => {
        console.log(e.data); // "Mess from iframe"
    })
</script>
```

*iframe.html*

```
<script>
    // Send message to index.html
    window.parent.postMessage('Mess from iframe', '*');

    // Get message form index.html
    window.addEventListener('message', e => {
        console.log(e.data); // "Message to iframe"
    })
</script>
```

[Demo on GitHub pages](https://slaawwa.github.io/iframe-data/) and [Code on GitHub](https://github.com/slaawwa/slaawwa.github.io/tree/main/app/_pages/iframe-data)

Answer (score 0):

This is **First.html**

```
 window.onload = function() {
  var varObject = {label:["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"], data:[65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40]};
  var child = document.getElementById("child");
  var childWindow = child.contentWindow;
  childWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(varObject),'*');
  console.log(childWindow.postMessage);
 }
```

This is **Secound.html**

```
  if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener("message", getData, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent("onmessage", getData);
  }
  function getData(e){
    let data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    alert('test');
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Thanks all of you , your suggestion make my answer create Thanks a lot.
You save my time